# Toggle button in HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a toggle button using the following, but its not working.
i have included CSS, HTML and javascript snippets I am using. If I am not doing something right, kindly advice.

CSS:

```
.toggle-button {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.toggle-button img {
  display:    inline-block;
  height:     30px;
  width:      60px;
  background: url(../images/on-button.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.toggle-button img.down {
  background: url(../images/off-button.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <head>
 <script Language="JavaScript">
     function toggle (img) {  
         $(img).toggleClass("down");
     }
 </script>
 </head>
 <div class="right-form">
     <h2>Email Settings</h2>
     <div class="toggle-button">
         <label>Stock Require Scanning:</label>
         <img ondblclick="toggle(this);" border="0 id="stock_require_scanning"/>
     </div>                    
     <div value="OFF" class="toggle-button">
         <label>Head Office Alerts:</label>
         <img ondblclick="toggle(this);" class="down" border="0" id="head_office_alerts"/>
     </div>                                    
 </div>
```

Is there anything I am not doing right?

Comment: I cannot see any jquery library out there in your code.?

Comment: toggle on double click ?

Comment: True, I want referencing jquery. So I did as the answer instructed and  I referenced jquery library and it worked. I also changed the toggle to be triggered onClick and not ondoubleclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a running demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L9nHY/ (I used the color green for "on" and red for "down"). Your made an error here:

```
<img ondblclick="toggle(this);" border="0"    id="stock_require_scanning"/>
```

You have to replace `this` with `'#stock_require_scanning'`:

```
<img ondblclick="toggle('#stock_require_scanning');" border="0"    id="stock_require_scanning"/>
```

The same you have to do for the other button.

**Edited: Sree:** See this also: http://jsfiddle.net/L9nHY/1/